# New Zealand boyfriend traveling to Iran with me

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, iran, invitation-letters, new-zealand-citizens

In 2 weeks, my Kiwi boyfriend is joining me to travel to Iran and visit my family. He is excited but I am a bit worried as what can go wrong.

I know he can get a visa on arrival but a website told us to get a visa document so he doesn't have to wait in the airport and he can just collect his visa on arrival. However his document visa got rejected, saying please apply via host. On the form, it asked where he is planning to stay during his holiday. I gave my parent's address and my dad's phone number in Iran. Hence, the comment for him to apply via the host. But there is no option no way to apply via host!

Should we just hope that his visa on arrival will go right and that the piece of document that got rejected wasn't important? My research so far says those documents are necessary for people traveling via travel agencies. Private ones don't need that because they have a host. but some confirmation would be nice please.

Comment: Just another note, if your boyfriend plans to travel to the USA soon; travel to Iran means he will no longer be eligible for the Visa Waiver Program and will have to apply for a B2 visa.

Comment: I don't think you will get into trouble if there is a host to contact (your parents) on arrival.

Answer (score 7):

New Zealander here. I arrived for a friend's wedding in Tehran. I told them so, got a visa on arrival, entire process took about 20 minutes.

Your experience may vary, but it was very straightforward for myself, and my friend who was also on a Kiwi passport.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify that it wasn't *your* wedding. :)

Comment: @GregHewgill indeed, it was not. Mine was 2.5 years later ;)